# Assign UserGroup to Role - Liferay 6.1.1

Tags: java, api, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I'm currently working with Liferay 6.1.1, and i'm coding a hook for default values.

Im desperatly looking for a way to assign userGroup to a Role via the API.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried it but can you do something like this

```
//Get group from UserGroup
Group group = userGroup.getGroup();
//Assign it to the role
GroupLocalServiceUtil.addRoleGroups(roleId, new long[]{group.getGroupId()});
```

Comment: Thanks I was about to update this post because I've tried this solution earlier and it worked. And now I just saw that u answered me. Thanks